# Type casting in OpenCL APIs (void *)&c_mem_obj

Tags: opencl

I have encountered a strange syntax inside armaments list of OpenCL host-code. However, I do not have any problem with my hostcode functionality but it is strange for me what does it mean at all and why it pass the arguments in this way.

clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&c_mem_obj);

To the best of my knowledge, it is type cast. am i wrong ?

i believe it does not have any special purpose since the  **clSetKernelArg** API already accept only pointer.

It is really helpful to have a more technical explanation.

thanks,
jimbo

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it is a type cast. It is taking the address of your `cl_mem` object (which is type `cl_mem *`) and casting it to type `void *` (and since clSetKernelArg takes a `const void *` it's not even the *best* cast).

**It is not required.** You could also just write `clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &c_mem_obj)` and it should compile (it does for our code, on Windows, Mac, and Linux).

Comment: Thanks!!! Yes you are right. it works without cast. I did not understood why they used this kind of syntax and since it was from NVIDIA benchmark it become more interesting for me.